# How to sync the database each time you create a model in flask using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Project tree structure.

```py
C:.
│   app.py
│   config.py
│   Dockerfile
│   requirement.txt
│
├───user_services
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───controller
│   │   │   create_user.py
│   │   │__   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───models
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   user.py
```

### app.py

```py
from user_services import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'], debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

### user_service/**init**.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

app = Flask(__name__)
if app.config["ENV"] == "production":
    app.config.from_object("config.ProductionConfig")
else:
    app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
api = Api(app)

# Creating Database and model!!
from user_services.models.database import user
if not database_exists(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']):
    print('Creating DB...!!')
    create_database(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    db.create_all()

from user_services.controller.create_user import CreateUser
api.add_resource(CreateUser,'api/v1/create/new_record')
```

### User Model:user.py

```py
from user_services import db



class UserDetails(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_details'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

And create_user.py will be the controller part which will insert the record .

### So the problem here is:

If i will add new model(table) to database , i have to delete the previous data from DB before running app.py . So how do i sync the model while running app.py .

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to initialise your database every time you run your app. I would suggest using [`flask-migrate`](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to manage your model changes as migrations.

This is more convenient and you will get all your change history and will be able to apply/roll back changes. You will also then get a CLI tool integrated with `flask` command to manage your database schema that you can use separately from running the app.